# For loop in r: how to store multiple outputs of each iteration in one row instead of in separate rows?

Tags: r, for-loop, rvest

I'm trying to store multiple outputs of each round of iteration in a for loop in r by running the following code, but the multiple outputs of each iteration were stored separately in different rows. The code I used and the results I got through this code is as follows:

Code I used:

```
result_issue <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:3){
  web <- read_html(link[i])
  news_issue <- web %>% html_nodes('li.m-list__item a')
  issue1 <- news_issue %>% html_text()
  this_result_issue <- data.frame(issue1)
  result_issue <- rbind(result_issue, this_result_issue)
}
result_issue
```

Results I actually got:
The first three rows is the output of the first iteration, the row 4 and 5 is the output of the second iteration, and the last three rows is the output of third iteration.

```
issue1
1 Facebook Fact-checks
2          Coronavirus
3         TikTok posts
4 Facebook Fact-checks
5       Facebook posts
6 Facebook Fact-checks
7          Coronavirus
8             Bloggers
```

Results I expect is like this: the output of each iteration is saved in one row

```
issue1
1 Facebook Fact-checks; Coronavirus; TikTok posts
2 Facebook Fact-checks; Facebook posts
3 Facebook Fact-check; Coronavirus; Bloggers
```

Please enlighten me if you have any ideas. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I cant recreate your data, but try changing `rbind(result_issue, this_result_issue)` to `c(result_issue, this_result_issue)` and see what that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you take this part of your code:

```
  web <- read_html(link[i])
  news_issue <- web %>% html_nodes('li.m-list__item a')
  issue1 <- news_issue %>% html_text()
```

and put it in `sapply`. The benefit of `sapply` is that the output vector is pre-allocated so that you are not creating a growing object. See [circle 2 of the R inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

In each step, to get `issue` as a single string separated by `'; '`, you can use `paste` with `collapse`.

Once you have the output vector you can use it to create a data frame.

```r
set.seed(10)

result_issue_vec <- 
  sapply(1:3, function(i) {
    # web <- read_html(link[i])
    # news_issue <- web %>% html_nodes('li.m-list__item a')
    # issue1 <- news_issue %>% html_text()
    issue1 <- sample(letters, sample(1:4, 1))
    paste(issue1, collapse = '; ')
  })

data.frame(issue1 = result_issue_vec)
#>       issue1
#> 1    i; j; p
#> 2 w; h; v; g
#> 3    s; x; o
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>